# What can be a harmless electrolytic additive for water for creating an oxy-hydrogen flame?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, applied-chemistry

I was thinking of preparing a tiny oxy-hydrogen flame for soldering. I am going to use 6V DC and aluminum sheet as the electrode for this. Now, I have to add some electrolyte to water, that can be a salt, base or acid. But, if I add $\ce{NaCl}$ or $\ce{HCl}$, they will produce chlorine. If I add $\ce{NaOH}$, it will eat electrodes. Adding $\ce{H2SO4}$ may produce poisonous gases like $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{H2S}$. So, what can be a harmless/least harmful electrolyte for such purpose? Is $\ce{Na2CO3}$ a good choice?

Comment: More importantly, this is a very bad way to create a flame. It will require far more effort than just buying a butane or propane torch.

Comment: @matt_black Obviously butane or propane torch are good ways, probably the best. But, I was just thinking of creating a flame myself or at least trying to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrolysis of water has become an increasingly common means of creating torches for soldering and welding, and there are commercial devices available as well as plenty of internet do-it-yourself sites. According to [this site](http://newatlas.com/safeflame-water-flame-torch/29673/) regarding the [SafeFlame consortium](http://www.safeflameproject.eu/what-is-safeflame/):

> "[...]the European Union-funded SafeFlame consortium has developed a
>   torch system that generates a flame using nothing but H2O and
>   electricity.   SafeFlame utilizes an electrical current to electrolyze
>   ordinary water, separating it into hydrogen and oxygen gas. Those
>   gases are then mixed and ignited as they exit the torch's nozzle. By
>   fine-tuning the proportions of the two gases, different types of
>   flames can be produced for different applications."

A commonly used electrolyte / electrode combination is $\ce{KOH}$ or $\ce{Na2CO3}$ with stainless steel electrodes. I believe this would be pretty corrosive toward aluminum, but stainless steel for such a setup should be cheap and easy to come by.